# Function A start Function B, how to ensure B continue to execute after A finishes

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust

A async function B is called in the async A function, and then the function C which runs a loop starts in A. How to ensure that C continues to execute after B finishes executing.

```rust
async fn A() -> Result<()>{
  // start B
  B().await?;
  Ok(())
}

async fn B() -> Result<()> {
  //start C
  C();
  Ok(())
}

fn C(){
  //running a loop
  loop{
    ...
  }
}
```

If possible, please attach a rust demo;

Comment: Start C on a new thread and don't join it.

Answer (score 1):

In standard rust, you would have to return `C()` without awaiting it, and have `A` await it, possibly concurrently with other futures. You could also spawn a thread to run `C()`, but that defeats the purpose of using async.

When you have a runtime, you can spawn it on that. For example, with [`tokio::task::spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.25.0/tokio/task/fn.spawn.html):

```rs
async fn B() -> Result<()> {
  //start C
  tokio::task::spawn(C());
  Ok(())
}
```

You may still want to return the `JoinHandle` to `A`.

If you are writing a library and don't want to depend on a specific runtime, you can take a function that accepts a future:

```rs
async fn B<F, R>(f: F) -> Result<R>
where
    F: FnOnce(Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send + 'static>>) -> R,
{
  let r = f(Box::pin(C()));
  Ok(r)
}
```

You may need different traits on `F` or `R`. I also don't think it is possible to do this without `Box`, unless you have access to [type alias impl trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/type-alias-impl-trait.html), or make a concrete `Future` type instead of using an async function.

[Here is a playground of this working.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4c719c7438067ebf6014767817da23ca)